# Max allowed size in Text field of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am doing a project where user can post text, i have used TinyText.
i need to know how much input user should be allowed to do ?
i came to know TinyText allows only 255 characters to be entered from 
http://www.htmlite.com/mysql003.php
But if a user enters & then it have to be converted to &amp and so...
So what should be the ideal size allowed to be inputted from the users for these field/data types

> > TinyText
> >     Text

User can insert data, but can not edit !
An user can view others data !
So, view will be used mostly !

Comment: This is impossible for us to answer. It all depends on your apps requirements.

Comment: i've written that in my app User will be inserting data only [no update/edit, delete is allowed but read will be used most]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you can find details about MySQL text type: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Comment: The following reveals more information about field sizes (in bytes): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think replacing html entities and insert them into your database lets you control the final length that is inserted into your tinytext.

I'd go for 2 options.

1. Insert raw data into the database, and use htmlentities on outputting.
2. Restrict it to an maximum amount of characters, but use a larger text-type.

Depending on your application I'd pick one.

Comment: yup u r right, but i think if i user htmlentities every time for showing data it will waste my CPU !

Comment: It is costly yes, but depending on your application you should be using caching anyway when you hit a significant amount of hits :)

Comment: thats true also, but i think i should use Varchar, i think it's better than Text